# DevTools disconnects when placing break points in script files

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm working with Chrome version 51.0.2704.103 m and [this simple project](https://github.com/jsmunroe/SilverGriffonJS). When I put a breakpoint in any other file than index.html, I get an "Aw, snap!" with the following message in DevTools:

[image]

It doesn't automatically reconnect when I reload.

Note: even though this project is all html and javascript, it will not run unless served.

Comment: it happened to me when memory consumption was too high. Check Chrome's internal task manager. Shortcut is Shift+Esc

Comment: That seems to have solved my issue. Thanks.

Comment: No I take that back. It worked at first, but now the problem is back. My memory in Chrome is very low.